# How do I project Datareader into a pre-defined object

Tags: c#, vb.net, async-await, sqldatareader

I need to know how to convert the following to VB.net for an Async/Await project:

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(
        this SqlDataReader reader, Func<SqlDataReader, T> projection) {

        while (reader.Read()) {
            yield return projection(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
'call the database asynchronously... and 'await' the results
Using reader = Await Db.GetReaderAsync("spGetDashboard", ParamList)
    Return reader.Select(Function(r)
                             Return New DashboardInfo With {.RowNum = CType(r.Item("RowNum"), Long?)}
                         End Function)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function [Select](Of T)(reader As SqlDataReader, projection As Func(Of SqlDataReader, T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    While reader.Read()
        Return CType(projection(reader), IEnumerable(Of T))
    End While
End Function
```

Here is the exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'WindowsApplication1.DashboardInfo' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WindowsApplication1.DashboardInfo]'.
>   at WindowsApplication1.Extensions.Select[T](SqlDataReader reader,
>   Func`2 projection) in
>   C:\Dev\AsyncDbTesting\AsyncDbTesting\Library\Extensions.vb:line 523
>   at
>   WindowsApplication1.Process.VB$StateMachine_1_GetDashboardAsync.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Dev\AsyncDbTesting\AsyncDbTesting\Process.vb:line 30
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   WindowsApplication1.Form1.VB$StateMachine_0_Button1_Click.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Dev\AsyncDbTesting\AsyncDbTesting\Form1.vb:line 17

Comment: While the vb.net code (at the bottom) complies, it throws an 'converting' error at runtime.

Comment: It didn't thrown an "error". It threw an "Exception". Please post the full exception - the Output of ex.ToString() after you catch the exception.

Comment: Please show us the full exception. Otherwise you're making us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is being thrown because you're trying to convert an item of type `T` into type `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Assuming you're using .Net framework 4.5, the code you want is

```
<Extension()>
Public Iterator Function [Select](Of T)(reader As SqlDataReader, projection As Func(Of SqlDataReader, T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    While reader.Read()
        Yield projection(reader)
    End While
End Function
```

Note that `Yield` and the concept of iterators don't exist in VB.NET before .Net framework 4.5.

Comment: I believe it's just `Yield`, not `Yield Return`.

Comment: Close... the Yield (without Return) compiles an runs but now my exception is:  Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Comment: My Exception had to do with my Using statement, inadvertently closing the reader before my loop was finished.

Comment: Edited code to remove `Return`. Thanks for spotting it, @StephenCleary